# Visual Studio 2013 update 1 Debug hangs when launching IE

Tags: internet-explorer, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging

Over the weekend, I decided I'd create a new Web Api 2 project. After doing so, and no additional changes I decided to use the "Start Debug Target" from the standard tool bar. It's the drop down button that shows "|> Internet Explorer." I've found something odd.

So just by doing the above, I've found Internet explorer loads the localhost:53461 and the page never comes up. If I hit refresh in IE, the page will load. In addition to this, I've found that when I press the stop button in Visual Studio, it takes it a long time to do so. I actually get a Debugger is stopped, but the system is still waiting dialog box. Where I can cancel or stop. (sorry I don't recall the actual message).

Of course if I check the Event Viewer, I see that IEXPLORER.EXE has an error message of app hang.

Now here's the oddity. Instead of doing the "|> Internet Explorer" and I decide to choose the browser, and select Internet Explorer from the dialog box, it launches IE just fine.

Also note that if I launch Chrome from "|> Chrome" it behaves as expected; meaning it loads it lightning fast.

Equally, at work, I don't experience these problems at all, while at home they're there. The only difference I can think of is I run Win 8 at work and Win 8.1 at home.

Has anyone experienced this before? How have you resolved it?

Comment: Hmmm very strange. Have you tried launching Visual Studio as an Administrator? I'd be curious if that might help.

Comment: Hi trnelson, It's a great idea, and it is how I launch Visual Studio.

Comment: Try launching Visual Studio in safe mode and let us know how it behaves.

Comment: Alan, thank you for the suggestion. In short, no dice (and sorry for the delay), I've tried safe mode, and it still hangs. I was hoping to get a log that showed more info, and even that didn't show anything. :(

Comment: I'm still struggling with this, so I've decided to open a ticket with Microsoft about it. I've even uninstalled IIS Express and VS 2013. Regardless, this is the link to the bug I've submitted: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/838881/visual-studio-2013-professional-update-1-hangs-when-debugging-in-ie-11#tabs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it's official, they patched this issue in an up and coming release for visual studio 2013.